# Determining FIRST sets of CFG

Tags: python, parsing, context-free-grammar

For LR-parsers the FIRST sets are defined as follows ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser)):

> FIRST(A) is the set of terminals which can appear as the first element
>   of any chain of rules matching nonterminal A.

Now given a CFG, that (I) does not allow empty productions (i.e. no rule is of format `X → ε`) and (II) is proper (i.e. no symbol produces itself), I am trying to determine the FIRST sets.

My reasoning is:

- As there are no empty productions, it is sufficient to look at the first symbol of the right hand side of each rule.
- For all rules `X → tα` (being t a terminal and α an arbitrary string of symbols), t is in FIRST(X).
- For all rules `X → Yα` (being Y a non-terminal and α an arbitrary string of symbols), all elements of FIRST(Y) are in FIRST(X).

As in the case of `X → Yα`, I need FIRST(Y) in order to determine FIRST(X), I came up with this recursive approach:

```
class Rule:
    nextId = 0

    def __init__ (self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.id = Rule.nextId
        Rule.nextId += 1

    def __repr__ (self):
        return 'R{}: {} → {}'.format (self.id, self.left, ' '.join (self.right) )

class Grammar:
    def __init__ (self, rules):
        self.rules = {rule.id: rule for rule in rules}
        self.symbols = set (symbol for rule in rules for symbol in [rule.left] + rule.right)
        self.nonTerminals = set (rule.left for rule in rules)
        self.terminals = self.symbols - self.nonTerminals
        self.calculateFirst ()

    def calculateFirst (self):
        self.first = {}
        for nonTerminal in self.nonTerminals:
            self.first [nonTerminal] = self.getFirst (nonTerminal)

    def getFirst (self, symbol):
        if symbol in self.first: return self.first [symbol]

        first = set ()
        for rule in (rule for rule in self.rules.values () if rule.left == symbol):
            prefix = rule.right [0]
            if prefix == symbol: continue
            if prefix in self.terminals: first.add (prefix)
            else: first |= self.getFirst (prefix)

        return first

#here be dragons
rules = [Rule ('S', ['E'] ), Rule ('E', ['T'] ), Rule ('E', ['(', 'E', ')'] ), Rule ('T', ['n'] ), Rule ('T', ['+', 'n'] ), Rule ('T', ['T', '+', 'n'] ) ]


g = Grammar (rules)
print ('Rules:')
for rule in g.rules.values (): print ('\t{}'.format (rule) )
for nonTerminal in g.nonTerminals:
    print ('First ({}) = {}'.format (nonTerminal, g.first [nonTerminal] ) )
```

For the grammar given on wikipedia, this yields the following:

```
Rules:
    R0: S → E
    R1: E → T
    R2: E → ( E )
    R3: T → n
    R4: T → + n
    R5: T → T + n
First (S) = {'+', '(', 'n'}
First (E) = {'+', '(', 'n'}
First (T) = {'+', 'n'}
```

For another grammar it yields:

```
Rules:
    R0: S → N
    R1: N → V = E
    R2: N → E
    R3: E → V
    R4: V → x
    R5: V → * E
First (V) = {'*', 'x'}
First (S) = {'*', 'x'}
First (N) = {'*', 'x'}
First (E) = {'*', 'x'}
```

My questions are:

**1. Will this algorithm halt for any given set of rules complying with I and II.**

**2. Does this algorithm actually produce the correct FIRST sets of all non-terminals for any given set of rules complying with I and II.**

**3. Is there some clever way to do this?**

I thank you in advance for your comments and answers.

**Nota bene**: I was unsure whether to post this here or on code-review, but as I do not know whether my code works (i.e. yields the expected results) I decided to post it here. If you feel that it belongs rather to CR, please let me know.

Comment: Does it work correctly, Try with a grammar with some variable relation `A --> Bα | other_productions, B---> Cα | other_productions, C--->Dα | other_productions, D--->Eα | other_productions`. I think code will be fail

Comment: Each `A → α | β` is nothing more than syntactic sugar for `A → α` and `A → β`. I am not using (E)BNF, but a context-free grammar that complies with the definition of such, which is "In formal language theory, a context-free grammar (CFG) is a formal grammar in which every production rule is of the form
V → w
where V is a single nonterminal symbol, and w is a string of terminals and/or nonterminals (w can be empty).".

Comment: Actually you didn't notice my grammar, notice relation `A--> B, B--->C, C--->D, D--->E` I am not sure try with some complicated grammars with this relation.

Comment: Here is my code I written in C in during my graduation (your 4/6 years  back) May be you find it helpful to check algorithim [**Code**](http://codepad.org/6Ln6X8ks)

Comment: your welcome!  here example format [input-1](http://codepad.org/c0BZzJpj) and [input-2](http://codepad.org/7ikLustu) to use this code use GCC under Linux

Comment: The caret (^) is epsilon?

Comment: Yes, `^` is epsilon I say Null symbol in comment in my code. Use the ULLMAN's book I mention in Code. I commented the steps-n according to given in book...

Answer (score 2):

I think your program will work, in the sense that it will terminate and produce the correct answer if there are no nullable non-terminals. (Self-referencing non-terminals should be fine.)

There is a clever way to do it. Isn't there always? As is often the case, the clever solution was thought up by [Robert Tarjan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Tarjan), although there are other clever solutions, too. However, for most grammars, its generally just about as fast to use a simple solution.

Define the relationship `A directly-starts-with V` where `A` is a non-terminal and `V` is any symbol; `A directly-starts-with V` if there is some production `A → V α`. For a grammar without nullable non-terminals, `FIRST(A)` is simply the transitive-closure of the `directly-starts-with` relationship, range restricted to terminals. Tarjan's algorithm (which computes the strongly connected components of a graph) leads to a fast and elegant solution to this problem.

There are other good algorithms for computing transitive closure. [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) is another popular choice. As you might guess looking at F-W, you can reduce transitive closure to something very similar to matrix multiplication; the same techniques which can be used to reduce the time-complexity of matrix multiplication also apply to transitive closure; however, they're not particularly useful in the real world.

Nullable non-terminals don't complicate the situation very much, as long as you can identify them (and that's really easy). You just extend `directly-starts-with` to include any symbol on the RHS which is only preceded by nullable non-terminals. The usual algorithm for identifying nullable non-terminals will give you `directly-starts-with` almost for free.